# Flutter - Number Format

Tags: flutter, dart, number-formatting

Is there a way to format a number :

```
from 1 to 1.00,
from 2.5 to 2.50,
from 2.1234 to 2.1234
so basically the number will have a minimum of 2 decimal places
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

A non elegant way using Intl package:

```
var f = NumberFormat('#.00###############', 'en_Us');
print(f.format(2.123400))
```

and you will get

```
2.1234
```

but if your number have more decimal digit than you have '#' in format string then it's not show.
For example

```
var f = NumberFormat('#.00##', 'en_Us');
print(f.format(2.123456))
```

you will get

```
2.1234
```

I think that way works most of cases.
Or you can make format function by yourself. Like this:

```
String formatNumber(double number) {
  int precision = 0;
  while ((number * pow(10, precision)) % 10 != 0) {
    precision++;
  }
  return number.toStringAsFixed(max(precision - 1, 2));
}
```

In this case you don't use Intl package. There is no problem with number of digit after dot. BUT i belive that is a much slower than using intl package.

Answer (score 0):

The [Intl](https://pub.dev/packages/intl) package has a set of formatting classes than can help with this use case in particular the [NumberFormat](https://pub.dev/documentation/intl/latest/intl/NumberFormat-class.html) Class

Answer (score 0):

you can use `someDoubleValue.toStringAsFixed(2)` what this does is it basically adds or removes floating points from value

Note: if you parse double from this result string again, it will convert back (5.00 => 5)

Example:

```dart
String parseNumber(value) {
  String strValue = value.toString();

  List parsedNumber = strValue.split(".");
 
  String newValue;
  if (parsedNumber.length == 1) {
    newValue = value.toStringAsFixed(2);
  } else {
    String decimalPlace = parsedNumber[1];
  
    if (decimalPlace.length > 2) {
    newValue = value.toString();
    } else {
    newValue = value.toStringAsFixed(2);
    }
  }
  
  return newValue;

}
```

Comment: That will work, but if the number has 3 or more decimal places it will not satisfy the condition. What I'm trying to do is if number is a whole number it will automatically add a '.00', then if the number has 1 decimal place it will add '.0' and if the number has 3 or more decimal places it will remain the same.

Comment: Then you can use basic if statement and parse the number, I am editing my answer accordingly